# SSL: What are the differences between Domain Validation and Extended Validation Certificates?

Tags: domains, https, security-certificate

I can get Extended Validation for cheaper than Domain Validation, yearly. What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 2):

Even if more costly, an [Extended Validation Certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) (EV SSL) versus [Domain Validated Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority#Domain_validation) (DV SSL) is much more worthwhile to have:

EV SSL's can only be issued by those certification authorities (CA's) who pass independent audits for [WebTrust](http://www.webtrust.org/homepage-documents/item27839.aspx), and requires [standardized issuing criteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate#Issuing_criteria). Visitors will also see a very noticeable green bar in the address bar of all modern browsers, which is becoming more recognizable now that online banks are using them.

DV SSL's on the other hand require no more validation then just sending an email to the domain admin or technical contact listed in its WHOIS record with a link in it to authenticate the owner of the domain (similar to a website requiring signup validation via email).

[This](http://www.digicert.com/dv-ssl-certificate.htm) also provides additional reasons why many top CA's do not offer Domain Validated SSL's.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.networksolutions.com/SSL-certificates/SSL-offer.jsp?siteid=8&channelid=P90C8S570N0B9A1D862E0000V100&promo=NCDISC0038&gclid=CKiaipDLsbgCFchxQgod4wEAlw&clickid=9873091584 I know they're legit as I've got domains through them.

Comment: Network Solutions is definitely legit :-) You can view other EV CA's [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate#Extended_Validation_certificate_identification), and compare the promotional prices for EV's on their respective websites.

Comment: So would you recommend going with their EV then? Or do you know any other more reputable sites that offer the same promo?

Comment: The chart there is a bit incorrect - GoDaddy uses the term "Premium SSL's" for example, so they're comparing GD's standard SSL in that chart. Their pricing looks good, but keep in mind, it's likely promotional for one year, which will have to be renewed, so try to find out what their renewal (non-promotional) pricing will be when you renew next year, and the years thereafter...

Comment: I'm not sure how long I will be going with them for more than a year, honestly. I'm sure they can't FORCE you to renew with them, so if worse comes to worse, I'll just cancel the auto renew.

Comment: Sure. Your users may notice if you remove an EV, though if just temporarily or moved to another CA, maybe not. BTW, I try to remain impartial when referring to product/services comparisons, so don't take that as a yea or nea :-)

Comment: No problem. Glad people here actually answer your questions thoroughly unlike Stackoverflow. They need people like you there. Haha. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I try to be as thorough as possible :-)