# What's the catch with a 4.99$ ssl certificate

Tags: https

I was browsing the web in search of a cheap SSL certificate just for domain validation.
Then I came across a site that sells a certificate for 5 year in a ridicules price of 4.99$ and the one year is also cheap 8.95$ I am wondering where is the catch?
Am I am missing something is it possible that they real and not cheaters?

Comment: The "5 year" is cheaper than the "one year" option?

Comment: Domain Validation certificates are not very trustworthy due to the way they are "validated" and thus are valued less than other certificates. See this for more: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50787/ssl-what-are-the-differences-between-domain-validation-and-extended-validation/50790?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible and normal. You can even get SSL certificates free at some providers (e.g. some only charge you for revoking one, but let you get one for free) which will be accepted by browsers.